# pymysql database storing error using python

Tags: python, mysql, database, arduino, mariadb

i am having a error in this program, i am trying to store my output in a database collected from temperature sensor using arduino program

python code

```
import serial
import pymysql

device = /dev/ttyACM0'
arduino = serial.Serial(device,9600)

data  = arduino.readline()
print (data)

connection = pymysql.conect("localhost","pi","","temperature_db) or die("cant connect to database")

print (connection)

with connection:
cursor = connection .cursor 
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tempLog (Temperature) VALUES (%s)" %(data))
connection.commit()
connection.execute()
```

this is how I have created my database.

[image: database]

and this is what i have written in my arduino code
[image: code]

and this is the error I received for python code

[image: errorcode1]

can anyone please help me to solve this issue and explain why I had that error and how it was fixed?

Comment: The error message indicates that the value of `data` that your code is trying to store in the database is not a number as you expect, but instead is a bytestring with quotes in it. In cases like this the simplest approach is usually to print out the SQL you are constructing before trying to execute it. Like this: `SQL = "INSERT INTO tempLog (Temperature) VALUES (%s)" %(data); print (SQL); cursor.execute(SQL)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO tempLog (Temperature) VALUES ({data.decode('utf-8').strip()}" )
```

Explanation

There are two issues that need to be corrected:

- The byte variable `data`  `(b'Temp: 26 C\r\n')` needs to be converted to a string and whitespaces ('r\n') stripped off using for example `data.decode("utf-8").strip()`
- The sql insert statement expect a quoted string value like this `VALUES ("Temp: 26C")`.

1. Example of the different steps using Python

```
#
# The current sql insert look like this. Notice the value type
#
>>> "INSERT INTO tempLog (Temperature) VALUES (%s)" %(data)
"INSERT INTO tempLog (Temperature) VALUES (b'Temp: 26C\\r\\n')"

#
# Convert data to a string and strip white spaces
#
>>> data = data.decode("utf-8").strip()
>>> "INSERT INTO tempLog (Temperature) VALUES (%s)" %(data)
'INSERT INTO tempLog (Temperature) VALUES (Temp: 26C)'

#
# Finaly add quotes to VALUES to pass data as a string
#
>>> "INSERT INTO tempLog (Temperature) VALUES (\"%s\")" %(data)
'INSERT INTO tempLog (Temperature) VALUES ("Temp: 26C")'

#
# Final suggestion using python f-string
#
cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO tempLog (Temperature) VALUES ({data.decode('utf-8').strip()}" )
```

2. Your code with the suggested modifications.

```
import serial
import pymysql

device = /dev/ttyACM0'
arduino = serial.Serial(device,9600)

data  = arduino.readline()

data = data.decode("utf-8").strip() # Convert to str and strip whitespaces
print (data)

connection = pymysql.connect("localhost","pi","","temperature_db") or die("cant connect to database")

print (connection)

with connection:
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    sql = ("INSERT INTO tempLog (Temperature) VALUES (\"%s\");" % data)
    print(f"sql: {sql}") 

    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        connection.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: is there an alternate solution for this?

Comment: Hi, what are you looking for? Another way to format the insert statement?

Comment: I've added your code and with the suggested modifications under point 2.

Comment: i don't know why but it still shows the same error. do i have to change the code in arduino or should i do something else to fix it?

Comment: is there an another way to fix it?

Comment: I've made some additional modifications. What does the output from `print(f"sql: {sql}")` say?

Comment: i am receiving invalid syntax for "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/sketchbook/python/rasp.py", line 25
    except Exception as e
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: print(f"sql: {sql}")      it says invalid syntax for this too      sql = "INSERT INTO tempLog (Temperature) VALUES (\"%s\");" % (data)    this one too and                             
 sql = "INSERT INTO tempLog (Temperature) VALUES (\"%s\");" % (data)

Comment: Hi, fixed some more typos and at the same time found a bug: `cursor = connection.cursor` should be `cursor = connection.cursor()` since it's intended be a function call.